# How to create a hyperlink using telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to create a hyperlink named [ABC](http://example.com/) which takes you to http://example.com/ using telegram api in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can use formatting option to do this](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options)

Example:

```
from telegram import ParseMode

bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text="<a href='http://example.com/'>ABC</a>", 
                  parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.HTML)
```

Comment: I added example to the answer. I hope it will help you.